# Indexing new data in the Open Data Cube

Tags: indexing, open-data-cube

The cube in  a box comes with an indexing script for Sentinel-2 data, as below

```
lon_center = XX.YY
lat_center = XZ.XY
buffer = 0.5

bbox = [lon_center - buffer, lat_center - buffer, lon_center + buffer, lat_center + buffer]

start_date = '2019-02-01'
end_date = '2020-02-28'

collections = ['sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs']

config = {
    'collections': collections,
    'bbox': bbox,
    'datetime': f"{start_date}/{end_date}"
}

STAC_API_URL = 'https://explorer.sandbox.dea.ga.gov.au/stac/'

os.environ['STAC_API_URL'] = STAC_API_URL
```

How to index the Landsat data and other datasets such as MODIS ?

Comment: Is your question about: how to index new data in the datacube?

Comment: @AndreaMassetti, Yes

Comment: What is not clear from the [documentation](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ops/indexing.html)? Have you tried the use cases provided in the docs but you get stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting Landsat data from?

Once you have a source of data, you need to have the following things:

- A product definition, which defines what each dataset metadata document should look like
- A dataset metadata document, one for each scene, either created in memory or as a file.

To do the above, you can read through documentation or [check out some examples](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-dataset-config).

For the Cube in a Box, I would love to be able to index off the USGS STAC API, but this requires some development work to achieve it.